# reuse query calculations with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have this (beginner) query:

```
  let getCandlesSQL =
        $"SELECT
               date_trunc('minute', ts) ts,
               instrument,
               MAX(price) high,
               MIN(price) low,
               (SUM(price * price * quantity) / SUM(price * quantity)) midpoint,
               SUM(price * quantity) volume,
               (SUM(direction * price * quantity) / SUM(price * quantity)) direction

        FROM {tableTradesName}
        WHERE instrument = '{instrument.Ticker}' AND ts BETWEEN '{fromTime}' AND '{toTime}'
        GROUP BY date_trunc('minute', ts), instrument
        ORDER BY ts
        LIMIT 4500"
```

I rebuild the string with internal variables at every call, so I don't need to use the SQL variable mechanism.

There are a few calculations that are done multiple times, for example 'price * quantity' is done many times.
Is there a way to write the query to do it once and then re-use it?

Comment: I suspect that's pretty low-hanging fruit for the query optimiser, and is done automatically already without having to write the query any different.

Comment: true, but that would help me learn how to do it as well